# Сериализация коллекции

Tags: c#, xml, .net, visual-basic, сериализация

Нужно сериализовать коллекцию **`ListBox.SelectedItems`**.

Пробовал через цикл **`For Each`**, но тогда создаются несколько корневых элементов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewExpression xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <expression>1/x</expression>
  <color />
  <width>5</width>
</ViewExpression>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewExpression xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <expression>x*x</expression>
  <color />
  <width>5</width>
</ViewExpression>
```

---

```
public class ViewExpression:Expression
{
    private Color _colr;

    private int _linewidth;

    Random R = new Random();
    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "color")]
    public Color Color {
        get { return _colr; }
        set { _colr = value; }
    }

    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "width")]
    public int LineWidth {
        get { return _linewidth; }
        set {
            if (value < 100 & value > 0) {
                _linewidth = value;
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли этого избежать?

Comment: Не помню код, но вероятно нужно будет создать новы объект типа коллекции или массива, засунуть в него выбранные элементы и его уже сериализовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте свой класс типа:

```
public class ListBoxSelectedItemsContainer
{
    public List<ViewExpression> Expressions;
}
```

Замапьте с помощью LINQ список выбранных итемов **ListBox.SelectedItems** на этот класс

```
var obj = new ListBoxSelectedItemsContainer();
obj.Expressions= listBox.SelectedItems.Select(x=>new ViewExpression(...)).ToList();
```

*(не забудьте объявить нужный конструктор ViewExpression(...))*

И теперь сериализуйте объект **obj**.

Comment: >    obj.SelectedItemsValues = listBox.SelectedItems.Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();

А если мне нужно чтобы объекты были своего типа?
Добавил описание класса к вопросу.

Comment: обновил ответ